# Error when fetching data from OpenWeatherMap while hosting on Github Pages

Tags: javascript, fetch, github-pages, openweathermap, unexpected-token

I am pretty new to coding and I wanted to code a weather website. So I am using the OpenWeatherMap API.

Everytime I wanna fetch the data from this API, I am getting the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcBFx.png

It seems like my code is conflicting with the code of github pages, because when I check where exactly the error is occurring, I noticed it is partially not in my code:

My Code:

```js
 // Fetches the weather data with the given url
    function fetchWeather() {
        if (positionError(lat, lon)) {
            let weatherURL = "https:/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&appid=" + apiKey + "&units=metric&lang=en";

            try {
                fetch(weatherURL)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        if (data["city"] !== undefined) {
                            console.log(weatherURL);
                        } else {
                            alert("Cannot fetch data for the given lat and lon values!");
                        }
                    });
            } catch (e) {
                console.error("Can't fetch url for weather!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Github pages Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; img-src data:; connect-src 'self'">
    <title>Site not found &middot; GitHub Pages</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      body {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      }

      .container { margin: 50px auto 40px auto; width: 600px; text-align: center; }

      a { color: #4183c4; text-decoration: none; }
      a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

      h1 { width: 800px; position:relative; left: -100px; letter-spacing: -1px; line-height: 60px; font-size: 60px; font-weight: 100; margin: 0px 0 50px 0; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff; }
      p { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); margin: 20px 0; line-height: 1.6; }

      ul { list-style: none; margin: 25px 0; padding: 0; }
      li { display: table-cell; font-weight: bold; width: 1%; }

      .logo { display: inline-block; margin-top: 35px; }
      .logo-img-2x { display: none; }
      @media
      only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
      only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
      only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
      only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
      only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
      only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) {
        .logo-img-1x { display: none; }
        .logo-img-2x { display: inline-block; }
      }

      #suggestions {
        margin-top: 35px;
        color: #ccc;
      }
      #suggestions a {
        color: #666666;
        font-weight: 200;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin: 0 10px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <h1>404</h1>
      <p><strong>There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.</strong></p>

      <p>
        If you're trying to publish one,
        <a href="https://help.github.com/pages/">read the full documentation</a>
        to learn how to set up <strong>GitHub Pages</strong>
        for your repository, organization, or user account.
      </p>

      <div id="suggestions">
        <a href="https://githubstatus.com">GitHub Status</a> &mdash;
        <a href="https://twitter.com/githubstatus">@githubstatus</a>
      </div>

      <a href="/" class="logo logo-img-1x">
        <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="">
      </a>

      <a href="/" class="logo logo-img-2x">
        <img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am gonna link my code and the webpage here: [Code from Github](https://github.com/daFinndus/Sunchecker)  -  [The Website](https://dafinndus.github.io/Sunchecker/?)

To recreate the error, you have to get your Position first, because you cannot fetch the weatherdata without a location. After you clicked the "get position"-Button, you have to "check weather". The error happens right then.

I already checked the .JSON file for any wrong characters or if anything is not working like it should be.

It is completely working on my local server, so it has to be a problem with github pages, but I really can't figure out what it is.

Comment: The error indicates you're fetching HTML, not JSON.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: You're getting a 404 Not Found error, and GitHub Pages returns an HTML error document with its 404 errors. So there's a problem with the URL.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, thank you very much for your advise.

The URL for the API seems fine tho, the JSON is correctly displayed and can be fetched on my local server, do you know what is interfering with my function on github pages?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about GitHub Pages. But the error document has this link to how to publish there: https://help.github.com/pages/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After visiting the site and checking the weather, I noticed something in the error that might help:

```
GET https://dafinndus.github.io/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=45.5202471&lon=-122.674194&appid=6b73bc848d05bdb699cf0cfb49adf6f6&units=metric&lang=en 404
```

When expanding the error to see the full URL, it looks like your own site's address is being added to the string. Then looking closer at the code, I think it could be as simple as missing a `/` in the URL: it should be `https://api.openweather......` I hope it's that straightforward!

My guess is that when the request sees the single slash it's assuming you want to look at a subdirectory of the current domain.

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you so much, it works! I would've never guessed that this is the problem! 

Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score -1):

This error is generated when trying to parse HTML to JSON.

There is an issue with the used URL.

Also, you have only one / after https.

Comment: Yeah, the slash was the problem. Didn't know github would change my link if it only contains one slash and not two. ^^